# What $L(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a)$ has to do with this problem at all? I am confused?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Following is the word problem:
Given the formula $L(x) = f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$, what is the linear approximation of the tangent line at $a=2$ for the following function $f(x)=x^3$?

After watching Khan Academy, I figured out that I have to find slope (derivative) of $f(x)$ which is $f'(x)=3x^2$, then plug-in 2 to get $f'(2)=3(2)^2=12$
then use point slope $(y-y1)=m(x-x1) \implies (y$ is found by plugging in 2 in the original $f(x)=x^3)$ implies
$$(y-8)=12(x-2) \implies y=12x-24+8 \implies y=12x-16$$ and this is correct answer.

But I have no idea why problem mentions formula $L(x) = f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$?

Comment: It is the same thing you just did

Comment: Compare $y-y_a =m(x-x_a )$ to $f(x)-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)$ ... $f'(a)=m$ and some point on the line $(x_a ,y_a )=(a,f(a))$. They just solved for $f(x)$ and called it $L(x)$.

Comment: Thanks randomgirl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This L(x) is the general formula for the linear approximation that you are looking for. You just have to plug in your $f$. So, in your case $$L(x)=a^3+\left.(x^3)'\right|_a(x-a)=a^3+3a^2(x-a)=3a^2x-2a^3$$ which is linear (in $x$). Now, plugging in $a=2$ you can confirm your result $$L(x)=3(2^2)x-2(2^3)=12x-16$$